# convert flv for playback on ipad

Tags: video, idevices, flv

I like to watch flv videos during downtimes using my ipad.  Whats a good tool for converting video files and then tossing them onto the ipad.  Primarily I've grabbed a few flv tutorials off you tube.   I know ffmpeg can do the transform, but it's got one of those "needs a phd in video" to sort out...

Answer (score 4):

Try:

- [Arista Transcoder](http://www.transcoder.org/) (Seems to be specially for devices like ipods/phones etc.)
- [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/) (GUI for FFMPEG)
- [OggConvert](http://oggconvert.tristanb.net/) (Converts to free formats)

These can all be found in the Ubuntu Software Centre.

EDIT: Arista is probably the best of these as it has a preset for the ipad.

Answer (score 1):

I find that [MediaCoder](http://mediacoderhq.com) works quite well for video transcoding. It has presets for iPod/iPad and runs just fine under Wine.

Answer (score 0):

Hands down best video encoder. [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

Handbrake is not available from the repositories. You can install it [from a ppa though](http://launchpad.net/~handbrake-ubuntu/+archive/ppa%3E;%20%E2%80%93%20dv3500ea):

<

Comment: Handbrake is not available from the repositories.
You can install it from a ppa though:
<https://launchpad.net/~handbrake-ubuntu/+archive/ppa>

Comment: In my experience, the version in the regular PPA doesn't work on Lucid: the "Start" button is grayed out. Use the more recent snapshots instead: `ppa:stebbins/handbrake-snapshots`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the codecs installed, you just need to learn one `ffmpeg` command to re-encode your videos:

```
ffmpeg -i in.flv -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -sameq out.mp4
```

For help with codecs, I recommend this useful page at [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu).